# How to hide component if edit is selected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular 8 application.

And I want to hide the component when edit is selected. Of course I know when a button function is triggered. You can do it with ngIf. But now you go to the edit page with a routerlink.

So this is the edit on the template view.component:

```
    <span>
        <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item', itemDossier.id]" routerLinkActive="active-link"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
         i18n-title title="Edit">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </a>
      </span>
```

So if you select the edit, then the view.component has to been hidden.

But how to do this?

Thank you

I tried like this:

```
 public router: Router
```

```
<div *ngIf="router !=''../', dossier.id, 'item', itemDossier.id'">

<app-view></app-view>
</div>
```

But I get a parse error:

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token ., expected identifier or keyword at column 13 in [router !=''../', dossier.id, 'item', itemDossier.id'] in c:/source/nien/kenjezelf/frontend-coach/src/app/dossier/components/view/view.component.html@1:5ng
```

view.component looks like this:

```
<app-dossier-personal-data> </app-dossier-personal-data>

   <span>
        <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item',
        itemDossier.id]" routerLinkActive="active-link"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
         i18n-title title="Edit">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </a>
      </span>
```

and so if the edit button is selected, then only this has to been shown:

```
<app-dossier-personal-data> </app-dossier-personal-data>
```

So I try it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '../+[dossier.id]+[item]+[itemDossier.id]'">
..What I have to fill in here?
</div>
```

Comment: try to set any bool variable for this.if you click the button set boolen variable as true in global and check the bool value in your componet.

Answer (score 0):

Just print this two things separately
console.log(router);
console.log('../', dossier.id, 'item', itemDossier.id')

Compare both and make necessary till you get the expected result. 
then keep it in *ngIf

Comment: ?? What do you mean

Comment: Concatenate the ../', dossier.id, 'item', itemDossier.id' into a new string and compare the router with this string.

Comment: Looks like router !="'../'+dossier.id+'item'+itemDossier.id'"